# Natural deduction: is $y$ free in $\forall x.p(x)$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I would like to understand a step in this (incomplete) gentzen-style natural deduction tree. For the $\forall I$ step it must hold that $y$ is not free in $\forall x.p(x)$. I don't understand why this holds. Obviously $x$ is not free in $\forall x.p(x)$ because $\forall x$ binds $x$, but $\forall x$ doesn't bind $y$, so $y$ could be free in $\forall x.p(x)$, or?

[image: example]

The rules are:

[image: Rule1]
[image: Rule2] with the $\text { Side condition } *: x \text { not free in any assumption in } \Gamma$

Comment: I think it is implicit here that $p$ is a $1$-place predicate symbol. If $p$ stood for a non-atomic predicate involving free variables other than $x$, then your objection is correct.